# Bootstrap print view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to print a invoice I built with HTML and Bootstrap CSS. However, when I try to print the content is not full width. I've changed the media from *screen* to *all*.

[Web Page View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGv46.png)

[Print View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9jLs.png)

**CSS**

```
@media print {
  * {
    text-shadow: none !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-width:0 0px 0px 0 !important;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/bootstrap.css" media="all">
```

Comment: put some markup to help you

Answer (score 0):

I have used in one of my application , hope it helps you.. 
Try to print content as follows

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="printContent('class or ID of your content')">Print Content</button>
```

**Script**

```
function printContent(el){
        var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing is tricky with most browsers - the issue is that depending on browser, default paper size and it's orientation (portrait or landscape) and the current tide in Sydney a page will print in 72ppi, 96ppi or 144ppi.

In Bootstrap the media query establishes a pixel width band... e.g. "xs" is between 544px-767px, so depending on the (printed) page width your site might revert to the "xs" or the "sm" width variants when printing.

One solution is to create a `@media print {}` media query that overrides classes like `.container` and all the `.col-*` classes.  (Yes... lots of work!)

There is also some plugin CSS' ... like my [vinorodrigues/print-ready](http://github.com/vinorodrigues/print-ready) that tries to account for some of this.  *(Excuse the self promo, but there is too much code to C&P into this answer.)*